# VSCode 1.3.1: Editors do not open in new tab

Tags: visual-studio-code

Clicking on a file in the Explorer opens it in the current editor tab
instead of opening a new editor tab. This effectively limits the
number of open tabs to a single tab. How can I change this behaviour
so that clicking in Explorer opens the file in a new tab?

Using the *File->Open File... Ctrl+O* menu command works as expected
and opens the file in a new editor tab.

Observed in:

- Win10 (fresh VSCode 1.3.1 install)
- Ubuntu MATE 16.04 (upgrade from VSCode 1.2.1).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the name of the file in the tab is in *italics* then the file is in "preview mode". Dbl-click on the tab name and it will change the filename font to normal font and then file will remain open.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining that. To make this behaviour permanent I set the `workbench.editor.enablePreview` setting to `false`.